# Angular router warning - did you forget to call ngZone.run()

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, agm-map

I am getting this error every time i am trying to redirect to a link in the same application from google map. I am using `agmmap` and angular 8. Here is the sample code

```
<agm-map <some configuration there>>
  <agm-marker <some configuration there>>
    <agm-snazzy-info-window <some configuration there> #infoWindow>
      <ng-template>
        <a routerLink="/details">{{'view_details' | translate}}</a>
        </ng-template>
    </agm-snazzy-info-window>
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

I am able to fix that issue using this [Tutorial](https://www.coditty.com/code/angular-router-navigate-warning-did-you-forget-to-call-ngzonerun), but i wanted to know like what is the root cause of it and is there any change / refactoring required in the code to resolve it? 
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is the package you're using for "google maps" an angular package? If not chances are it is written in plain JavaScript or even jQuery, but does not trigger the change detections angular heavily relies on. Only chance is to either wrap certain parts of the code manually into the angular "zone", or use another angular-based package.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner, Thanks, Yes it's an angular package . https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap

Answer (score -1):

This error asks you to call ngZone.run().

Since your error occurred every time you wanted to redirect to the same application google map you should call ngZone.run() after grantOfflineAccess().

grantOfflineAccess will be called when the user grants the requested scope (according to [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthgrantofflineaccessoptions))

I recommend you to read the error messages probably, this will lead you to fix  90% of the issues